# How to set value to the field in pojo model in spring boot which has another pojo model in it(Many to One Mapping)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, pojo

I would like to set value to the field in model which is another model in spring boot.(Many to one mapping) **without using NEW Keyword**.
Please consider below example,

```
public Class Model_1 {

private someFields;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
  private Trade dTrade; 
}
```

**Other Model :**

```
public Class Model_2 {

private id;

}
```

Now i want to set value to id field in Model_2 class, so we do like below

Model_1 modelOne = new Model_1;

Model_2 modelTwo = new Model_2;
modelTwo.setId(1);

modelOne.setDtrade(modelTwo);

Like i mention above is the usual way to achieve it.

Could you please let me know any other way around to achieve it **without USING NEW KEYWORD** which creates new instance and facing some issue due to that. I want to achieve without the new keyword for some reason. Kindly let me know. Really Appriciated and much thanks.

Thank you !!!

Comment: Unless you have an existing instance of Model_2, this isn't possible. Maybe you should try figuring out (asking for) a solution to your "some issue due to that" instead.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the suggestions and time :)